# How to set the InnerException of custom Exception class from its constructor

Tags: c#, .net, exception, logging, reflection

How can I set the `InnerException` property of an `Exception` object, while I'm in the constructor of that object? This boils down to finding and setting the backing field of a property that has no setter.

BTW: I have seen this [evain.net - Getting the field backing a property using Reflection](http://evain.net/blog/articles/2009/05/01/getting-the-field-backing-a-property-using-reflection) but looking for non IL-based solution, if possible.

The constructor of `Exception` is the place where the `Exception` type is created, so I cannot call it using the base class constructor `MyException() :base(...)` etc.

Comment: Re the follow up; then (as I mentioned) do the type creation in a static method *ahead* of the ctor, instead of inside the constructor body.

Comment: Makes more sense to encapsulate in my case.

Comment: ...but I take your point, I'll look into making this a factory to avoid the reflection cost.

Comment: (fwiw, I didn't say factory; look at the example - you can use a static method to do work *just before* the base ctor, in the call to base; you put your work here, and presto)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why can't you just call the constructor taking the InnerException as a parameter? If for some reason it's not possible, the backing field in System.Exception is:

```
private Exception _innerException;
```

I found it out using [Redgate's Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/). Using reflection I suppose you could set the inner exception.

**Edit:** In most cases it's not a good idea to access private fields via reflection, but I don't know enough about NT's case to know for sure if it's a good or bad idea.

Comment: I can't think of a sensible example where reflection is the right way to do this...

Comment: It makes sense for dynamic scenarios involving activations of exceptions where the inner exception cannot be known in advance, therefore cannot be passed to the constructor.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It really doesn't; it breaks encapsulation. Use a static method in the ` : base(SomeMethod(...), ...)` chain.

Comment: @_NT: For the inner exception to make sense it should occur before the current exception.  Typically you want to bubble exceptions up... not down.

Comment: BTW... changing private and internal values with reflection may cause breaking changes in the future. If you do this it's at your own risk.

Answer (score 100):

You set the inner exception by calling the base ctor:

```
public MyException(string message, Exception innerException)
       : base(message, innerException) {...}
```

If you need to run some code to get the exception, use a static method:

```
public MyException(SomeData data) : base(GetMessage(data), GetInner(data)) {...}
static Exception GetInner(SomeData data) {...} // <===== your type creation here!
static string GetMessage(SomeData data) {...}
```

Answer (score 58):

The `Exception` class has an overloaded constructor accepting the inner exception as a parameter:

```
Exception exc = new Exception("message", new Exception("inner message"));
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Whilst this doesn't answer his question directly, it answers what most people who searched for this were looking for.

Comment: @rollsch is right.

Answer (score 11):

```
Exception exceptionWithMoreInfo = new Exception("extra info", ex);
```

would be normal practice assuming you've trapped an exception to which you'd like to add more information before bubbling up.

Comment: This doesn't help you in the exception's ctor, though.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't `InnerException` supposed to be set when using the `Exception(string, Exception)` constructor? I think it's by design that you can't change this otherwise but you can always defer to the appropriate constructor at construction time:

```
class MyException : Exception {
    public MyException()
        : base("foo", new Exception("bar"))
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

I think you shouldn't ever break the exception chain in your code since that usually leads to errors you will never find again.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question you want to do something like this:

```
Exception ex = new Exception("test");
Exception innerEx = new Exception("inner");
ex.GetType().GetField("_innerException", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(ex, innerEx);
```

If you are in the constructor of an object that inherits from Exception you would use `this` instead of the first `ex`.

But this may not be the best way to handle whatever it is you are trying to handle.

Comment: What's wrong with Exception innerEx = new Exception("inner"); Exception ex = new Exception("test", innerEx); ?

Comment: He is trying to modify the object ex which was not created in the context, I create it just for the purpose of demoing. Actually in his case he is trying to modify the this instance.

Comment: +1: This answered my own rather silly question of how to force an exception's inner exception to be itself, thus causing fun things like having the ToString() method trigger a stack overflow.

Comment: @Brian: And this is precisely the reason why .NET Framework does not expose setting the inner exception. If an exception can be linked to an existing exception, and this association can never change, then the exception chain is guaranteed to be finite. If you could change the inner exception, you can no longer make this guarantee - you can recursively loop the exception chain to itself.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm really late to the party, but I find that this works.

```
public class MyException: Exception
{
    public void SetInnerException(Exception exception) 
    {
        typeof(Exception)
            .GetField("_innerException", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .SetValue(this, exception);
    } 
}
```

The trick is to get the actual `Exception` type's `_innerException` field, and then set the inner exception value to your class instance (`MyException` in this case).

This also works for variables.

```
Exception mainException = new Exception();
typeof(Exception)
    .GetField("_innerException", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .SetValue(mainException , new Exception("Something bad happened!"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Redgate's Reflector to find the field. I doubt the Exception implementation will ever change... But it is a risk!

Comment: Why would you doubt this? What basis do you have for making this assessment? If I were Microsoft, I'd change the implementation just to spite fools who depend on internal implementation details of other people's classes.

Comment: Based on the amount of such details that have changed over the past framework updates?

Comment: The real reason isn't that the internal implementation of the `Exception` class could change. (There's no guarantee it won't, but there's no reason to believe it will.) Rather, it's that by accessing and modifying the private fields, you are violating the class invariants: by only allowing an exception to chain to an existing exception and never allowing this association to change, it is guaranteed that the exception chain will always be finite and will never recursively loop to itself.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation I used this code:

```
class Foo 
{
    void Bar(MyException myException = null)
    {
        try
        {
            SomeActions.Invoke();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (myException != null)
            {
                // Here I regenerate my exception with a new InnerException
                var regenMyException = (MyException)System.Activator.CreateInstance(myException.GetType(), myException.Message, ex);
                throw regenMyException;
            }

            throw new FooBarException("Exception on Foo.Bar()", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

HTH someone ;).

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods work well.

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class ExceptionExtensions
    {
        public static void SetInnerException(this Exception exception, string innerExceptionMessage)
        {
            typeof(Exception)
                .GetField("_innerException", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .SetValue(exception, new Exception(innerExceptionMessage));
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your catch block when you want to add the inner exception:

```
try
{
    throw new Exception("Main Message");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ex.SetInnerException("Inner Message");
    throw;
}
```